# Enterprise Architect Quick LInker Arrow Hide/Show

Tags: enterprise-architect

My quick linker arrow has disappeared.  After looking at the user guide, I cannot find how hide/show it.  It was there last week, but not today.  I had my friend open up the same file on his computer and the quick linker arrow is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick linker can be switched on or off by going to `Tools > Options > Links` and setting or clearing the Quick Linker "Enable" option.